# _penter and _pexit symbols not seen

Tags: windows, assembly, visual-c++, dll, linker-errors

Writing a solution in Windows using Visual Studio 2013 C++ and trying to get the _penter and _pexit hooks working.

Getting  `error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _pexit` and  `error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _penter` for all my project files when I compile it with /Gh and /GH. I have a solution with two projects - one my main project compiled with /GH and /Gh and another DLL project which defines `_penter` and `_pexit` in an assembly file(wrote a seperate assembly file for it since my application is x64).

If I have another symbol(a different function in the DLL), that is being seen and I am able to call it from the other project and it works properly as expected, but when I compile with /GH and /Gh options its not finding the definitions for `_penter` and `_pexit`. Not able to find why this happens.

Also, if I try to write the `_penter` and `_pexit` in the cpp file itself, it gets exposed and the other project is able to see it. But I cant write inline assembly in x64, so I've written it in a seperate asm file but that doesnt get exposed.

Also, I tried writing a `def` file as follows,

```
LIBRARY   EXTLIB
EXPORTS _penter
EXPORTS _pexit
```

and point my main project to it, it gives me these two errors,

```
1>------ Build started: Project: MyProj, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>Definitions.def : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _penter
1>Definitions.def : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _pexit
1>..\..\build\MyProj.lib : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

when I dont give the def file, the errors are like,

```
1>Reality.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _pexit
1>Reality.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _pexit

...
```

for all my files in the project.

What am I doing wrong? How do I make my project see the definition for `_penter` and `_pexit`?

EDIT:

```
    extern entry:Proc
extern exit:Proc
PUBLIC _penter
PUBLIC _pexit
EXPORTS _penter
EXPORTS _penter
.code
    PUSHREGS    macro
        push    rax
        push    rcx
        push    rdx
        push    r8
        push    r9
        push    r10
        push    r11
    endm
    POPREGS macro
        pop r11
        pop r10
        pop r9
        pop r8
        pop rdx
        pop rcx
        pop rax
    endm
_penter proc
    push rax
    lahf
    PUSHREGS
    sub rsp, 8+16
    movdqu xmmword ptr[rsp], xmm0
    sub rsp ,8
    sub  rsp,28h    
    mov  rcx,rsp
    mov  rcx,qword ptr[rcx+136]
    call entry
    add  rsp,28h
    add rsp, 8 
    movdqu xmm0, xmmword ptr[rsp]
    add rsp, 8+ 16
    POPREGS
    sahf
    pop rax
    ret
_penter endp
_pexit proc
    push rax
    lahf
    PUSHREGS
    sub rsp, 8+16
    movdqu xmmword ptr[rsp], xmm0
    sub rsp ,8
    sub  rsp,28h 
    mov  rcx,rsp
    mov  rcx,qword ptr[rcx+136]
        call exit
    add  rsp,28h
    add rsp, 8 
    movdqu xmm0, xmmword ptr[rsp]
    add rsp, 8+ 16
    POPREGS
    sahf
    pop rax
    ret
     _pexit endp
end
```

Comment: you wrong do something in dll project. show asm file compile options and how you defined this function in asm

Comment: My assembly file contains this, `PUBLIC _penter` and `_penter proc` below which the body sits, and the dll contains `extern "C" void __declspec(dllexport) _cdecl _penter(void);` and thats all. My main project is compiled with /Gh and /Gh. If I expose a different function the same way I am able to call it from my main project

Comment: @MichaelPetch I changed my assembly file to this, `PUBLIC penter` and `penter proc` below which the body sits, and the dll to `extern "C" void __declspec(dllexport) _cdecl penter(void);`  I still get the same errors. Did I do it right? Or should I do something different? I am new to this.

Comment: Also forgot to mention that my asm file also has this - `EXPORTS _penter
EXPORTS _pexit`

Comment: no, must be exactly `_penter` and `_pexit`. show asm compile options. not need any `extern "c"` etc

Comment: @RbMm Added my exact asm file and my dll file contains this `extern "C" void __declspec(dllexport) _cdecl _penter(void);
extern "C" void __declspec(dllexport) _cdecl _pexit(void);` in a header file(which I *dont* include in my main project).

Comment: @MichaelPetch in x64 must be exactly `_penter` and `_pexit`. in x86 - `__penter` and `__pexit`

Comment: `EXPORTS _penter` are this line compile in *ml64*? this must be in *def* file. you not need any header files. you not need declare `extern "C" void __declspec(dllexport) _cdecl _pexit(void);` - nonsense. you not need `PUBLIC _penter` because all symbols with `proc endp` already public. but i ask about ml compile options. are `/Cp` exist ? and simply look in .obj file for `_penter` and `_pexit` symbols - in which exactly form ?

Comment: I think a better question is this. Did you add MASM as a build customization to your project? If you didn't by default your files won't be assembled.

Comment: @MichaelPetch - with this agree. based on line `EXPORTS _penter` in asm possible it was not processed at all. need add custom build stem in vs. usual `ml64 /c /Cp /Zd $(InputFileName)` -> `$(InputName).obj`. but single underscore `_` must be in *x64* in functions names. in x86 - double - `__`

Comment: And you don't need to add a special customise line. You can get Visual Studio to do it for you. Load up your project, right mouse click on the project, select `build dependencies` then select `build customizations` and then add `MASM` (it will be in the list). If you do this AFTER you added assembly files to the project you'll have to then right mouse click each ASM file and mark the files to NOT be excluded from the build. By default they will be.

Comment: @MichaelPetch - again - you mistake. the `_` **must be** because this is part of original function name. must be `_pexit` on x64 and `__pexit` on x86.

Comment: Thanks both of you! I added /EXPORT:_penter /EXPORT:_pexit in the linker command line in Visual Studio of my DLL project and alas they are being seen, it compiles successfully! Looks like the EXPORT in the asm file was not honored. Now let me see if it works as expected.

Comment: @MichaelPetch - must be exactly `_penter proc ** _penter endp` and `_pexit proc ** _pexit endp` in x64 asm

Comment: @user9639921 - but you initially use correct def file. use def

Comment: @MichaelPetch - no, if i correct understand english. must be **exactly** `_penter` and `_pexit` in x64 asm file. we can not remove **all** underscore. the initial underscore - this is not decoration. this is part of original function name. and this name is *CL* hardcoded. we can not change it and we not need declare it in c/c++. we never direct call it. this is compiler internals

Comment: fact in that - we never declare `_penter` and `_pexit` in c/c++ files. *CL.exe* know this 2 names without declaration. and we not call it direct. *CL* implicit insert this calls. the initial `_` is part of name. so it must be in any asm file. simply in *x86* asm - need be 2 `__` - `__pexit` and `__penter`, when in x64 not need aditional `_` - just `_pexit` and `_penter`

Comment: As far as I know the linker will implicitly add an underscore (`_`) to function names in ".def" files (unless you use a more complex syntax). When your ".def" file contains the function name `_penter` this actually means `__penter` (with 2 underscores).